# Calling InstallPackageAsync with my custom FolderNuGetProject does not install files

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

When using the v6.3 `Nuget.Packaging` and `NuGet.PackageManagement` libaries, I am unable to install packages like I can when using v.4.0 equivalent.

It seems to be releated to my `PluginProject.InstallPackageAsync` override, v6 throws a null refernce exception but not with v4. Not calling the `base.InstallPackagesAsync` fails to install any packages in my folder so im sure its key.

```
// Class is derived from FolderNuGetProject and method overidden
public override async Task<bool> InstallPackageAsync(PackageIdentity packageIdentity, DownloadResourceResult downloadResourceResult,
    INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, CancellationToken token)
{
    var result = await base.InstallPackageAsync(packageIdentity, downloadResourceResult, nuGetProjectContext, token);
    await _packagesConfigProject.InstallPackageAsync(packageIdentity, downloadResourceResult, nuGetProjectContext, token);
    return result;
}
```

Even when using the `FolderNuGetProject` directly, it throws - so I have found the source of the error need to debug the source to understand why... `nuGetProjectContext.PackageExtractionContext` is null.

[image: object null ref]

**Detail**

I writing an app which has plugins downloadable from nuget, which can then be dynamically loaded into my application - [similair to this interesting talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4VqiwQbQZ-k).

I derive my class from the NuGet.ProjectManagement.FolderNuGetProject, however files are not installed after calling `NuGetPackageManager.InstallPackageAsync` with my custom folder project, only `packages.config` is updated per below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Unified.Mqtt.Pattern" version="1.0.3" targetFramework="netstandard2.0" />
</packages>
```

But no files in the directory other than that:

```
PS C:\ProgramData\unified.msp> dir

    Directory: C:\ProgramData\unified.msp

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        07/08/2022     11:07            156 packages.config
```

The Project class is below:

```
public class PluginProject : FolderNuGetProject
{
    private readonly PackagesConfigNuGetProject packagesConfigProject;

    public PluginProject(string root) : base(root)
    {
        this.packagesConfigProject = new PackagesConfigNuGetProject(root, new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "TargetFramework", NuGetFramework.AnyFramework },
            { "Name", "My.Package.Installer" }
        });
    }

    public override Task<IEnumerable<PackageReference>> GetInstalledPackagesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return this.packagesConfigProject.GetInstalledPackagesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task<bool> InstallPackageAsync(PackageIdentity packageIdentity, DownloadResourceResult downloadResourceResult,
        INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // THIS LINE THROWS NULL REFERENCE WITH v6, BUT NOT v4
        var result = await DeletePackage(packageIdentity, nuGetProjectContext, token);
        await 
        packagesConfigProject.UninstallPackageAsync(packageIdentity, nuGetProjectContext, token);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And the overall plugin manager is below (which scaffolds everything together into the `NuGetPackangeManager` method calls. It does list installed packages, and can install (ableit without the actual file contents):

```
public class NugetPluginManager
{
    private readonly IOptions<NugetPluginManagerSettings> settings;
    private readonly LoggerAdapter logger;
    public NugetPluginManager(IOptions<NugetPluginManagerSettings> settings, ILogger<NugetPluginManager> logger)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
        this.logger = new LoggerAdapter(logger);
    }

    private static (SourceRepository Repository, List<Lazy<INuGetResourceProvider>> Providers) GetRepository(string repositoryUrl)
    {
        var providers = new List<Lazy<INuGetResourceProvider>>();
        providers.AddRange(Repository.Provider.GetCoreV3());
        var packageSource = new PackageSource(repositoryUrl);
        var repository = new SourceRepository(packageSource, providers);

        if(packageSource.SourceUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
            throw new ArgumentException($"{repositoryUrl} is not https.", nameof(repositoryUrl));
        return (repository, providers);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<PackageReference>> GetInstalledPackages(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var commonApplicationDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
        var rootAppPath = Path.Combine(commonApplicationDataPath, "unified.msp");
        var packagesPath = Path.Combine(rootAppPath, "packages");
        var project = new PluginProject(rootAppPath);
        return await project.GetInstalledPackagesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task Install(string repositoryUrl, string packageName, string version, bool includeDependencies,
        bool includePreRelease, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var (repository, providers) = GetRepository(repositoryUrl);

        var commonApplicationDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
        var rootAppPath = Path.Combine(commonApplicationDataPath, "unified.msp");
        var packagesPath = Path.Combine(rootAppPath, "packages");

        var project = new PluginProject(rootAppPath);

        var defaultSettings = Settings.LoadDefaultSettings(rootAppPath, null, new XPlatMachineWideSetting());

        // Create the package manager - TODO: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8479
        #pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
        var repositoryProvider = new SourceRepositoryProvider(defaultSettings, providers);
        #pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete

        var packageManager = new NuGetPackageManager(repositoryProvider, defaultSettings, packagesPath)
        {
            PackagesFolderNuGetProject = project
        };

        var dependencyBehaviour = includeDependencies ? DependencyBehavior.Lowest : DependencyBehavior.Ignore;

        var resolutionContext =
            new ResolutionContext(dependencyBehaviour, includePreRelease, false, VersionConstraints.None);

        var projectContext = new EmptyNuGetProjectContext();

        await packageManager.InstallPackageAsync(
                                packageManager.PackagesFolderNuGetProject,
                                new PackageIdentity(packageName, NuGetVersion.Parse(version)),
                                resolutionContext,
                                projectContext,
                                repository,
                                Array.Empty<SourceRepository>(),
                                cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stepping into the source code with Resharper the error the PackageExtractionContext was missing! Adding below resolved this:

```
var settings = Settings.LoadDefaultSettings(root: null);

var projectContext = new EmptyNuGetProjectContext()
{
    PackageExtractionContext = new PackageExtractionContext(
        PackageSaveMode.Defaultv3,
        XmlDocFileSaveMode.Skip,
        ClientPolicyContext.GetClientPolicy(settings, this.logger),
        this.logger)
};

await packageManager.InstallPackageAsync(
    packageManager.PackagesFolderNuGetProject,
    new PackageIdentity(packageId, NuGetVersion.Parse(packageVersion)),
    new ResolutionContext(DependencyBehavior.Ignore, false, false, VersionConstraints.None),
    projectContext,
    _repository,
    new SourceRepository[] { },
    CancellationToken.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

> `nuGetProjectContext.PackageExtractionContext` is null.

This is obviously because the package is missing in the first place! :3

> When using the v6.3 `Nuget.Packaging` and `NuGet.PackageManagement` libaries, I am unable to install packages like I can when using v.4.0 equivalent.

Of course, you're gonna have to install them manually in the code you provided in your answer!

Tip: Since you're using a newer version, it is highly possible the `PackageExtractionContext` package is no longer compatible with the new version, and have to be installed by you manually.

This applies for many libraries and extensions with its packages.